# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send, Error on windows XP

Tags: c#, winforms, webservice-client

I have a simple asmx webservice, im calling it from windows forms, it works on windows 7,8 and 10  but when i run this winform on windows XP sp3 with .net 3.5 installed, i get the error:

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred
>   on a send"

I have tested this on 4 different systems, and all give me this error,
I googled about this, and find many links saying set KeepAlive property of httprequest to false on webservice like below:

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);
    //Setting KeepAlive to false
    webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    return webRequest;
}
```

i tried this, but i still have the problem

Comment: I know it's an old one, but did you find the resolution to this, Saeed?

Answer (score 0):

This error tends to mask other issues.

This often occure to me when there is a problem with either my query string, or the service had some sort of an unhandled exception.

I would first check the connection string, and if all is well with it (in my case, generally didn't update the password...), debug the service I'm trying to contact.